# SyntaxError for curly brackets while defining a dictionary in VS Code

Tags: python, dictionary, visual-studio-code, graph-theory, python-3.7

I am trying to define a dictionary for an undirected graph in python 3.7.4. Yet, it keeps showing invalid syntax error to me:

```
graph = {
         a: ["b", "d"], 
         b: ["a", "c"],
         c: ["b", "d"],
         d: ["c", "a"]
        }
```

The structure I've used:
https://www.python-course.eu/graphs_python.php

[image: Screenshot of VS Code]

Comment: What are `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` in your code?

Answer (score 0):

Your keys are not string literals, but variables named `a`, `b`, `c` and `d`, which you presumably have not defined. You probably meant for them to be strings:

```
graph = {
     "a": ["b", "d"], 
     "b": ["a", "c"],
     "c": ["b", "d"],
     "d": ["c", "a"]
    }
```

Comment: 30 seconds faster... :-D

Comment: Dear Mureinik, thank you for your answer. I have edited the code, the nodes(a,b,c,d) are now strings. But still, I am receiving the same syntax error as before and it's mentioning the curly brackets. I am confused, because it's the structure used for dictionaries and I am defining a dictionary                                                                graph = {
         "a": ["b", "d"], 
         "b": ["a", "c"],
         "c": ["b", "d"],
         "d": ["c", "a"]
        }                                                                    
ERROR: }
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 0):

If you're using chars as key then use quotes, if `a`,`b`,`c` and `d` are variables then they have to be either a string/char or an integer.

```
graph = {
         "a": ["b", "d"], 
         "b": ["a", "c"],
         "c": ["b", "d"],
         "d": ["c", "a"]
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you want the keys in the dictonary to be strings:

```
graph = {
     "a": ["b", "d"], 
     "b": ["a", "c"],
     "c": ["b", "d"],
     "d": ["c", "a"]
    }
```